# Why am I not getting any values back?

Tags: java, return

When running the below method, I do not get anything back. Always getting terminated without any results. Could someone tell me why I am not getting any results back?

I hava adjusted according to the comments but havent worked. I have add the main method below;

```
public class ModuleGrader {
final int examID = 123;
String excellent =null;
String good=null;
String satisfactory=null;
String compensatableFail=null;
String outrightFail=null;
int grade;

public String gradeModule(int mark) {
    String result = null;
    if (mark>=70 && mark<=100) 
    {
        result = excellent;
        System.out.println(" ");
        }
    else if (mark>=60 && mark<=69)
    {
        result = good;
    }
    else if (mark>=50 && mark<=59)
    {
        result = satisfactory;
    }
    else if (mark>=40 && mark<=49)
    {
        result = compensatableFail;
    }
    else if (mark>=0 && mark<=39) {
        result = outrightFail;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid entery, please insert an number between 100-0");
                }

    return result;
}
```

So I have add my invoking main method;

the method to call maybe the problem?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ModuleGrader mg=new ModuleGrader();
        mg.gradeModule(100);
        mg.gradeModule(66);}
```

Comment: What number are you passing in?  What do you mean you're not getting any result?  You should at least get back `null`.

Comment: I get terminated. I have add the main method for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assigned no values to `String excellent;`, `String good;`, so it fails because those values have not been initialized to anything when you call them.

1. How would you know that it is not working? You have no output of the final result to the console. I added `System.out.println()` to correct that.
2. You can't reference something which is not static from something which is static. Change `public class ModuleGrader` to `public static class ModuleGrader`.

**Final Working Code**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ModuleGrader mg=new ModuleGrader();
        System.out.println(mg.gradeModule(100));
        System.out.println(mg.gradeModule(66));
    }
    public static class ModuleGrader {
        final int examID = 123;
        String excellent = null;
        String good = null;
        String satisfactory = null;
        String compensatableFail = null;
        String outrightFail = null;
        int grade;

        public String gradeModule(int mark) {
            String result = null;
            if (mark >= 70 && mark <= 100) {
                result = excellent;
                System.out.println(" ");
            } else if (mark >= 60 && mark <= 69) {
                result = good;
            } else if (mark >= 50 && mark <= 59) {
                result = satisfactory;
            } else if (mark >= 40 && mark <= 49) {
                result = compensatableFail;
            } else if (mark >= 0 && mark <= 39) {
                result = outrightFail;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid entery, please insert an number between 100-0");
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

<s>You need to put quotes around the strings you want to assign.</s>

`result = excellent;` should be `result = "excellent";` and soforth for all your assignments to `return`

Comment: Hi,I have created them as instance variable (strings). the code was running fine, but not sure why it's terminating now without result.

Comment: Your code runs fine and returns stuff when they are converted to strings.

Comment: public class ModuleGrader {
 final int examID = 123;
 String excellent;
 String good;
 String satisfactory;
 String compensatableFail;
 String outrightFail;
 int grade;

Comment: I have updated my code as above, yet I am getting no results?

Comment: Thank you very much. I add the System.out.println() to the output and it workes.

Comment: No problem. If this answer works for you, click the check mark to the left of my answer so this issue is wrapped up.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ModuleGrader {
    final int examID = 123;
    //String excellent=null;
    //String good=null;
    //String satisfactory=null;
    //String compensatableFail=null;
    //String outrightFail=null;
    int grade;

    public String gradeModule(int mark) {
        String result = null;
        if (mark>=70 && mark<=100) 
        {
            result = "excellent";
            System.out.println(" ");
            }
        else if (mark>=60 && mark<=69)
        {
            result = "good";
        }
        else if (mark>=50 && mark<=59)
        {
            result = "satisfactory";
        }
        else if (mark>=40 && mark<=49)
        {
            result = "compensatableFail";
        }
        else if (mark>=0 && mark<=39) {
            result = "outrightFail";
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid entery, please insert an number between 100-0");
                    }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I updated my code to the following, yet I am getting no results back?